# Creating noisy choatic wave like animations in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to achieve choatic waves on the screen as if, your computer was about to explode.  In photoshop, the concept was created by a noise filter and then pushing a wave filter through the noise to give it this appearance[image: noise screen]  I've created the noise using `<canvas>` element but would anyone have any ideas on how to push a wave through the noise or any other way to get this desired effect?

*I have 4 example jsfiddles that could be a starting point:*
Thanks to [Ken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/ken) for these examples:

[really close starting point that i found](http://csh.bz/sbcs/)

[JSfiddle Color noise](http://jsfiddle.net/5z2ck/)

[JSFiddle bluescreen noise](http://jsfiddle.net/vX7NK/11/)

[JSFiddle flicker blue noise](http://jsfiddle.net/t4Pvq/11/)

**JS:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// a variant using fixed canvas size but strecthes the result.
// emulates interference/bad reception
// using a different "noise" algo
canvas.width = canvas.height = 256;

function resize() {
    canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
}
resize();
window.onresize = resize;

function noise(ctx) {

    var w = ctx.canvas.width,
        h = ctx.canvas.height,
        idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h),
        buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),
        len = buffer32.length,
        i = 0,
        pr = 456 * Math.random(),
        prs = 716 * Math.random();;

    for(; i < len;) {
        buffer32[i++] = ((pr % 255)|0) << 24;
        pr += prs * 1.2;
    }

    ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
}

var toggle = true;

// added toggle to get 30 FPS instead of 60 FPS
(function loop() {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if (toggle) {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        return;
    }
    noise(ctx);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    background:#0000cc;
    margin:0;
}
#canvas {
    position:fixed;
    background:#0000dd;
    opacity: .2;
}
```

[reference question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ5Ti.jpg)

Comment: You could always use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/DAShs/ to generate the waves and you could combine it with using globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";  to get static looking waves (https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html)

Comment: I'm reading the post... i'm a big noob when it comes to canvas.  Any answers would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add waves you could extend the noise code I wrote there with the following:

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/wLzzQ/)

```
// add a var to global/parent scope
var offset = 0;

// modify method like this:
function noise(ctx) {

    var w = ctx.canvas.width,
        h = ctx.canvas.height,
        idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h),
        buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),
        len = buffer32.length,
        i = 0,
        pr = 456 * Math.random(),
        prs = 716 * Math.random();;

    for(; i < len;) {
        buffer32[i++] = (((pr % 255)|0) << 24) | 0x440000;
        pr += prs * 1.2;
    }

    ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
    
    // wave (utilizes GPU in modern browsers)
    for(i = 0; i < w; i += 2) {
        var y = i * Math.sin((i + (offset++)) /100);
        ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, i,0, 1, h,  i, y, 1, h);
    }
}
```

What happens here is that it renders first the noise, then it scans the canvas horizontally and offset them based on a more or less random sinus offset. We add to the global variable to animate it.

The slicing used to be slower in the past but in modern browsers with GPU hardware support this should run pretty fast.

All the values I used in the original code and this version are pretty much random. Just play around with offsets, sizes etc. to see if you get the result you are after.

You can change contrast by altering the last part on the "alpha" line:

```
0x440000
```

Just note that colors are arranged as ABGR in low-level buffers on little-endian machines (like the Intel CPU).

**Update**

Here is a more colorful version:

### [Demo (more colors)](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/cLMes/)

The only thing changed is this line:

```
buffer32[i++] = (((pr % 255)|0) << 24) | 0x770000 + (Math.random() * 16777216)|0;
```

(I am sure it can be improved in many ways, but just play around with it).

Saw the new link (starting point) in question - it's quite a bit different than what I imagined (based on the posted image). You would need an entirely different approach for that..

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Ah, `drawImage` for a 1-pixel-wide rectangle… And I had though of creating the random image, then transforming it pixel-by-pixel to a new location :/

Comment: @Bergi that should work too. Pixel displacement can be pretty fast with a 32-bit buffer. Hmm.. imagining wave looked at from above...

Comment: Ken I was trying to seek you out earlier to ask you an amended question lol.  But you found me.  would you know how to add a bit more color to streams >_<... this is literally my first canvas project... I'm in way over my designer head.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood I saw this by accident actually, just looking at the front page of SO and detected a new canvas question :) For colors: just manipulate the "alpha" line.. let me get back to cave and make a mod.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood back from the cave, updated the answer